# MCSE SharePoint certification

Tags: sharepoint-server, certification

I am bit of confused with the MCSE SharePoint certification. To complete this first I need to complete O365 MCSA and then do I need to complete any one of the exam from  below?

- Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013- 331
- Advanced Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 -332
- Core Solutions of Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 - 341
- Advanced Solutions of Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 - 342

What are list of exams to complete MCSE SharePoint certification? I checked Microsoft site but it is bit of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one thing to note that, after March 31, 2017 Microsoft will going to change the certification name from [`MCSE: SharePoint`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx) to [`MCSE: Productivity`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcse-productivity-certification.aspx)

So if you want to get certified now then you have to do the following exam.

**MCSA(O365)**

- Managing Office 365 Identities and Requirements (Exam 346)
- Enabling Office 365 Services (Exam 347)

Then pass this exam:

- Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016  (Exam 339)

After march 31, 2017, the certification title will be `MCSE: Productivity`. First, you have to get MCSA in O365 or Windows 2012.

MCSA:

**Office 365**

- Managing Office 365 Identities and Requirements (Exam 346)
- Enabling Office 365 Services (Exam 347)

**Windows Server 2012**

- Installing and Configuring Windows Server 2012 (Exam 410)
- Administering  Windows Server 2012   411
- Configuring Advanced Windows Server 2012 Services (Exam 412)

After MCSA then you have to Pass one of the following exam to complete the `MCSE: Productivity`.

- Designing and Deploying Microsoft Exchange Server 2016   (exam 345)
- Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016 (exam 339)
- Deploying Enterprise Voice with Skype for Business 2015  (exam 333)
- Core Solutions of Microsoft Skype for Business 2015  (exam 334)
- Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013   (exam 331)
- Advanced Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013   (exam 332)
- Core Solutions of Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 (exam 341)
- Advanced Solutions of Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 (exam 342)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have to do at least MCSA first and then I will decide based up on my exam dates

Answer (score 1):

To get the MCSE SharePoint cert, you have to first complete the MCSA O365 as you stated, which involves taking exams 346 and 347.

To complete the MCSE SharePoint cert you then have to complete the 339 exam, as per Microsoft's notes here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/learning/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx

Once you have the MCSE SharePoint cert, you then have to get recertified every 3 years.

Completing one of the exams listed in your question, in addition to having the MCSA O365, gets you the MCSE Productivity certification.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I am perfectly clear about the exams.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark my reply as an answer if it did the job ;)

Comment: Isn't this changing from every three years to having to do a refresher exam every year